# Iterator for REST API: skip and take

Tags: rest, rust, iterator

I'm thinking about implementing `std::iter::Iterator` for an existing REST API. The API accepts parameters for `skip` and `take`, simply by adding to the query parameters (`...&skip=10&take=10`).

It would be nice if I could make use of these parameters by sending in whatever is used for the Iterators `skip()` and `take()`. Since Rust iterators are lazy it feels like this would be doable. But all I find when looking for implementing Iterator is the `next()` method.

Example:

```rust
let result = api.search("something").skip(5).take(10).collect();

// In my iterator implementation I'd like to make the following request:
// https://my.api.endpoint/?search=something&skip=5&take=10
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Iterator` trait only has a single *required* method, to wit, the `next()` method. This method *must* be implemented for all types implementing the trait. All other methods of the `Iterator` trait are *provided* methods. They have default implementations, and you don't *have to* implement them, but you are still allowed to override them for specific types.

However, you cannot change the declarations of `skip()` and `take()`:

```
fn skip(self, n: usize) -> Skip<Self> where Self: Sized;
fn take(self, n: usize) -> Take<Self> where Self: Sized;
```

So these methods *consume* the old iterator, and return *new* iterators of type `std::iter::Skip<Self>` or `std::iter::Take<Self>`, respectively. After calling one of the methods, you won't be able to control the semantics of the second method in the chain, since that method will be called on one of these two type from the standard library rather than your custom type, so you will end up calling the default implementation of the method.

You can make `skip()` mostly work as you intend by overriding `nth()` on the iterator, since the implementations of `Skip` and `Take` forward `nth()` to the underlying iterator, but making `take()` work properly is not possible.

I recommend separating the parts of the API building the query and iterating over the results. For the latter, the `Iterator` trait is fine, but for the former you should define a custom interface.